# Python script that finds recently edited files (edited two days before till now)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to come up with a Python script to find all recently edited files on the computer.

Below is the code.

```
import os
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=48)

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            print('%s modified %s'%(path, mtime))
```

Comment: Could you describe what the problem with the above code is?

Comment: @Thymen it shows only the current python file and .\.idea\workspace.xml file. may you pls help me modify it, so that I may be able to see all recently edited files on the system. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On linux, mtime is returned as UTC whereas on windows it's localized.
Also, datetime objects are dumb (don't bother about timezones by default) so we're better of using timestamps.

Here's a working version that uses `ofunctions.file_utils` package in order to traverse paths. `ofunctions.file_utils` also happens to have a `file_creation_date()` function ;)

First install the package with

```
python -m pip install ofunctions.file_utils
```

Then use the following script

```
import os
import datetime as dt

if os.name == 'nt':
    now = dt.datetime.now().timestamp()
else:
    now = dt.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
ago = 86400 * 2  # Since we deal in timestamps, lets declare 2 days in seconds

files = get_files_recursive('.')
for file in files:
    mtime = os.stat(file).st_mtime
    if mtime > now - ago:
        print('%s modified %s'%(file, mtime))
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of ofunctions

Comment: thank you for the clarification but on *if mtime > utcnow - ago:*  I am getting unsupported operand type for -: '_module' and 'int'

Comment: Yes, I renamed utcnow to utc and forgot to update the later comparaison. I've fixed the code (and tested it on my platform). Does it work for you?

Comment: It has worked perfectly as I expected it to. Thank you. :)